# Equality of limits and "if and only if"

Tags: logic, proof-explanation

I'm reading Tao's analysis book, and he gives an example that I'd like to be sure I understand the intuition of. He starts with $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and the limit
$$
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x^n.
$$
He sets $n = m + 1$, so
$$
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x^n = \lim\limits_{m+1 \to \infty} x^{m+1} = x \lim\limits_{m+1 \to \infty} x^m. 
$$
He then observes that if $m + 1 \to \infty$, then $m \to \infty$. I assume the reason is that the $1$ isn't changing, so if $m+1$ is changing, the only thing that can change is the $m$ itself, so it must be going off to $\infty$. (My explanation here is not rigorous at all, so if someone can explain it more rigorously, I'd appreciate it.) He then goes on to write
$$
\lim\limits_{m+1 \to \infty} x^m = \lim\limits_{m \to \infty} x^m.
$$
However, I've only considered the implication in one direction. If $m+ 1 \to \infty$, $m \to \infty$; I didn't also consider $m \to \infty$ implies $m + 1 \to \infty$, though I believe it also to be true. But do I need to?

My main question is: do I need to check both directions for the limit equality to actually hold, or is one enough? What is the relation here between equality of limits and biconditional operators?

Comment: @ryang How about in the case of a continuous function, though? Say that $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $p$. Then if $p_n \to p$, then $f(p_n) \to f(p)$, but the converse is not necessarily true. Is it not valid to write $\lim\limits_{p_n \to p} = \lim\limits_{f(p_n) \to f(p)}$ because the converse does not hold?

Comment: I apologize. I think I misread your original comment. Just to be sure I fully understand in this context: that condition for continuity is only a one-sided implication, but the limit relation is an equality, just by virtue of the limit definition. Is that the idea?

Comment: @ryang Can you explain what $A$, $B$, and $P$ are in this context?

Comment: @ryang This is very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A(m):=\quad m\longrightarrow\infty\\
B(m):=\quad m+1\longrightarrow\infty\\
P(x,m,l):=\quad x^m\longrightarrow l$

\begin{gather}
\lim\limits_{m \to \infty} x^m \;\text{exists}\tag1\\
∃l{\in}\mathbb R \;\Big(\big(A(m) {\implies} P(x,m,l)\big)\Big)\tag1\\
A(m){\iff} B(m)\tag2\\
B(m){\implies} A(m)\tag3\\
∃l{\in}\mathbb R \;\Big(\big(A(m) {\implies} P(x,m,l)\big) \;\text{and}\; \big(B(m) {\implies} P(x,m,l)\big)\Big)\tag4\\
∃l{\in}\mathbb R \Big(\big(A(m) \;\text{or}\;B(m)\big) {\implies} P(x,m,l)\Big)\tag4\\
\lim\limits_{m \to \infty} x^m = \lim\limits_{m+1 \to \infty} x^m\tag4
\end{gather}

I think the intended reasoning is that $$\Big((1) \;\text{and}\; (2)\Big)\implies (4).$$

Unfortunately though, $$\Big((1) \;\text{and}\; (3)\Big)\kern.6em\not\kern-.6em\implies (4).$$